# Sort table by TD except first two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a pretty challenging sorting problem for a price table which has to be sorted by columns not rows.

The problem is an unsorted table:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Cheapest</td>
         <td>Option 1</td>
         <td>Option 2</td>
         <td>Option 3</td>
          <td>Option 4</td>
          <td>Option 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Price 1</td>
         <td data-price="20.82">€ 20,82</td>
         <td data-price="100.95">€ 100,95</td>
         <td data-price="300.20">€ 300,20</td>
         <td data-price="0"></td>
          <td data-price="158.72">€ 158,72</td>
          <td data-price="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Price 2</td>
         <td data-price="55.66">€ 55,66</td>
         <td data-price="100.95">€ 100,95</td>
         <td data-price="0"></td>
         <td data-price="128.72">€ 128,72</td>
         <td data-price="158.72">€ 158,72</td>
         <td data-price="105.22">€ 105,22</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to accomplish:

- The table needs to be sorted from left to right (columns)
- The first two columns have to stay at there positions (dont sort)
- The value to be sorted is in the data-price attribute
- An empty value is repesented by a 0 value and has to be at the end
- If there are multiple empty values, they have to be sorted on the second row value

[I created a Fiddle to show the desired result and explain a little more](http://jsfiddle.net/CgpS3/)

I have found enough solutions for sorting by rows or td by only one single row. I cant figure this challenging one out.

Comment: You have more than 1 row, but sorting the column just depends on the `data-price` of the cells on the same row, so looks like we can sort the column ***based on any row***? Otherwise the sorting may be complicated, such as in the first row we have `5,3,7,2` the order should be `2, 3, 5, 7`, but with that sorted order, the second row may have `4,3,5,7` which is not in an ascending order at all (it should be `3, 4, 5, 7`). Looks like your data should be consistent to avoid such a case happens.

Comment: The sorting has to happen **only** on the **first** row with data-price.
However, there are some empty values (0) on the first rows. Only empty  columns need to be sorted by the SECOND row. (See the JSFiddle)